# unauthorizedaccessexception - fix for saving xml file?

Tags: asp.net, xml, vb.net

I have checked the folder permissions on the folder and on the file making sure Write is granted.

Saving an xml file in vb.net yields a `System.UnauthorizedAccessException was unhandled by user code' error.

I thought creating an xml file and reading/updating with jQuery was a good idea now I wish I had done a simple vb.net storedprocedure call to a new image table.

What do I need to do in order to save an xml file using vb.net. I have moved the config file to the App_Data folder.

```
    ' update xml
    Dim doc As New XmlDocument
    Dim tempNode As XmlNode
    Dim childNode As XmlNode

    doc.Load(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/App_Data/referal_Image_Config.xml"))

    For Each tempNode In doc.DocumentElement
        For Each childNode In tempNode.ChildNodes
            If childNode.Name = "imageStartTime" Then
                childNode.InnerText = xmlStartDate

                doc.Save("referal_Image_Config.xml")
            End If
        Next
    Next
```

Comment: I would suggest you add a path to the Save function. The executing folder might night be the one you think.

Comment: @the_lotus my research indicates this needs to be a hardcoded path correct? i.e c"\app\images\ ?

Comment: Depends on where you want to save your file. If you want to save it at the same location as the load, then just do: doc.Save(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/App_Data/referal_Image_Config.xml"))

Comment: Be carefull, if two request are made at the exact same time. You might end up with a conflict trying to save the document at the same time. I don't have the big picture of your program but maybe it would've been a better idea to save this information in a database.

Comment: @the_lotus exactly my fear.. ugh.. there must be a way to check if it is open/or being saved?